# re-use properties for multiple ant build files?

Tags: ant

How can I have just 1 properties file be included into all of my ant build scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property tag for each of your ant build files and point to the same property file:

```
<property file="config/build.properties"/>
```